# JSON support in Internet explorer 9

Tags: json, internet-explorer-9

running this in IE9:

```
if (typeof(JSON) === 'object' && 
    typeof(JSON.parse) === 'function') {
  // Native JSON parsing is available.
}
```

It does not support native json. What do I wrong? 
Could there be wrong security settings in my IE ?

Comment: In jquery core they check it like `if ( window.JSON && window.JSON.parse ) {
   return window.JSON.parse( data );
  }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps your page is in quirks mode? I believe you need standards mode for IE9 to enable JSON.

Make sure you don't have any weirdness before your `<!DOCTYPE` and make sure it's one that triggers standards mode in IE9.

Comment: I have this: <!DOCTYPE html> bah its the compatibility mode... Thanks meder.