# Ajax, PHP return json get in Internet Explorer

Tags: ajax, json, internet-explorer

I am use Ajax with PHP and return JSON. Chrome and Firefox work well, but in Internet Explorer not return message what i want, it show save dialog instead.

Bellow is my PHP code that return json:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$jstatus     = 'My message...';
$status_data = array("code" => "1", "status"=> $jstatus);
echo json_encode($status_data);
```

In Internet Explorer can not catch it in ajax but show dialog "Do you want to open or save...".

- I don't know why this appear in Internet Explorer, and others browsers work well?

Comment: Which IE are you using? It's possible it doesn't recognize application/json as a valid content-type.

Comment: i test it with IE version 8 and 9

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787272/json-support-in-internet-explorer-9) to see if maybe you aren't enabling standards mode through your doctype.

Actually maybe that didn't say what I thought, sorry. Worth a shot anyway.

Comment: here is what i use: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">